# Videos Won't Display Subtitles

Tags: subtitles

Even though i add subtitle files (.srt) from external subtitles menu, the app won't display subtitles. How can I make the videos app display the subtitles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to overcome this glitch. After adding or changing the subtitles, just play/pause video for one or two times with the space bar and voila! Your subtitle is there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non answer answer.

Tying watching a video using VLC and see if you can get the subtitles to work.

> sudo apt-get install vlc

This will help in seeing if it is the video player or the subtitle file.